# How do I iterate over an array of objects and check if an attribute exists?

Tags: python

I have an array of `Order` Objects, each with their own set of attributes, one of which is `ticket_number`.

All `Order` objects have the attribute `ticket_number`; some of them may have a value, some of them maybe `Blank` or `Null`.

In an array of Order objects called Order, how do I check if each object has this attribute or not? I want the function to return true if it exists for even one of the objects and return false if it doesn't exist for all of them.

I tried this:

```
 def has_ticket_number(Order):
    for orders in Order:
        if orders.ticket_number:
            result = True
        else:
            result = False

    return result
```

But it always returns false. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: All orders have a property called ticket_number, some may have a value, some maybe blank or null

Comment: "has this attribute" - meaning some don't have an `ticket_number` at all and trying to reference it gives you an `AttributeError` - or the attribute is always there and you want to see if something is in it. If that latter, can you reword your question a bit?

Comment: @tdelaney There, reworded.

Comment: Your wording is still confusing.  Your question is `how do I check if each object has this attribute or not`, yet you explicitly state `All Order objects have the attribute ticket_number`.  You have answered your own question!

Comment: @JohnGordon Lol, Ok, English is not my native language, but since you understand what I mean(?), you tell me what the right words would be and I'll change it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Return `True` when you find the first one:

```
def has_ticket_number(Order):
    for orders in Order:
        if orders.ticket_number:
            return True
    return False
```

Even simpler, use the [any()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#any) function:

```
def has_ticket_number(Order):
    return any(orders.ticket_number for orders in Order)
```

Comment: Yeah this works perfectly! I did not know about `any`, thank you so much!